# Access XAML object in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, modal-dialog

How could I access a XAML object in my ViewModel? I am really confused. I want to access the `<Controls:ModalContentPresenter>` object. How could I realise this in a MVVM conform way? On this object I want to call a method `ShowModalContent`

```
<Controls:ModalContentPresenter x:Name="modalContent">
    <ScrollViewer Behaviors:AdvancedZooming.KeepInCenter="true" Visibility="{Binding LeerformularIsVisible}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddFieldDefinitionCommand}" Header="Feld hinterlegen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Designer/field.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddFunctionCommand}" Header="Funktion hinterlegen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Designer/FI_Taschenmesser_16x16.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding RemoveFieldDefinitionCommand}" Header="Aktuelle Felddefinition entfernen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Designer/remove_field.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding CutCommand}" Header="Ausschneiden" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Zwischenablage/FI_Ausschneiden_16x16.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" Header="Kopieren" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Zwischenablage/FI_Kopieren_16x16.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding PasteCommand}" Header="Einfügen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Zwischenablage/FI_Einfuegen_16x16.png" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>

        </Viewbox>

    </ScrollViewer>

    <Controls:ModalContentPresenter.ModalContent>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
            <Button>Hide</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Controls:ModalContentPresenter.ModalContent>
</Controls:ModalContentPresenter>
```

The code of *ModalContentPresenter* can be found here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Controls
{
    [ContentProperty("Content")]
    public class ModalContentPresenter : FrameworkElement
    {
        #region private fields
        private Panel layoutRoot;
        private ContentPresenter primaryContentPresenter;
        private ContentPresenter modalContentPresenter;
        private Border overlay;
        private object[] logicalChildren;
        private KeyboardNavigationMode cachedKeyboardNavigationMode;
        private static readonly TraversalRequest traversalDirection;
        #endregion

        #region dependency properties
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsModalProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsModal", typeof(bool), typeof(ModalContentPresenter),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnIsModalChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), typeof(ModalContentPresenter),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnContentChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ModalContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ModalContent", typeof(object), typeof(ModalContentPresenter),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnModalContentChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OverlayBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OverlayBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(ModalContentPresenter), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(204, 169, 169, 169)), OnOverlayBrushChanged));

        public bool IsModal
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsModalProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsModalProperty, value); }
        }

        public object Content
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public object ModalContent
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ModalContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ModalContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public Brush OverlayBrush
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(OverlayBrushProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OverlayBrushProperty, value); }
        } 
        #endregion

        #region routed events
        public static readonly RoutedEvent PreviewModalContentShownEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("PreviewModalContentShown", RoutingStrategy.Tunnel,
        typeof(RoutedEventArgs), typeof(ModalContentPresenter));

        public static readonly RoutedEvent ModalContentShownEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ModalContentShown", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventArgs), typeof(ModalContentPresenter));

        public static readonly RoutedEvent PreviewModalContentHiddenEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("PreviewModalContentHidden", RoutingStrategy.Tunnel, 
        typeof(RoutedEventArgs), typeof(ModalContentPresenter));

        public static readonly RoutedEvent ModalContentHiddenEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ModalContentHidden",  RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
        typeof(RoutedEventArgs), typeof(ModalContentPresenter));

        public event RoutedEventHandler PreviewModalContentShown
        {
            add { AddHandler(PreviewModalContentShownEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(PreviewModalContentShownEvent, value); }
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler ModalContentShown
        {
            add { AddHandler(ModalContentShownEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(ModalContentShownEvent, value); }
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler PreviewModalContentHidden
        {
            add { AddHandler(PreviewModalContentHiddenEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(PreviewModalContentHiddenEvent, value); }
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler ModalContentHidden
        {
            add { AddHandler(ModalContentHiddenEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(ModalContentHiddenEvent, value); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ModalContentPresenter implementation
        static ModalContentPresenter()
        {
            traversalDirection = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First);
        }

        public ModalContentPresenter()
        {
            layoutRoot = new ModalContentPresenterPanel();
            primaryContentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
            modalContentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
            overlay = new Border();

            AddVisualChild(layoutRoot);

            logicalChildren = new object[2];

            overlay.Background = OverlayBrush;
            overlay.Child = modalContentPresenter;
            overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            layoutRoot.Children.Add(primaryContentPresenter);
            layoutRoot.Children.Add(overlay);
        }

        public void ShowModalContent()
        {
            if (!IsModal)
                IsModal = true;
        }

        public void HideModalContent()
        {
            if (IsModal)
                IsModal = false;
        }

        private void RaiseModalContentShownEvents()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(PreviewModalContentShownEvent);
            OnPreviewModalContentShown(args);
            if (!args.Handled)
            {
                args = new RoutedEventArgs(ModalContentShownEvent);
                OnModalContentShown(args);
            }
        }

        private void RaiseModalContentHiddenEvents()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(PreviewModalContentHiddenEvent);
            OnPreviewModalContentHidden(args);
            if (!args.Handled)
            {
                args = new RoutedEventArgs(ModalContentHiddenEvent);
                OnModalContentHidden(args);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPreviewModalContentShown(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaiseEvent(e);
        }

        protected virtual void OnModalContentShown(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaiseEvent(e);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPreviewModalContentHidden(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaiseEvent(e);
        }

        protected virtual void OnModalContentHidden(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaiseEvent(e);
        }
        #endregion

        #region property changed callbacks
        private static void OnIsModalChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ModalContentPresenter control = (ModalContentPresenter)d;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
            {
                control.cachedKeyboardNavigationMode = KeyboardNavigation.GetTabNavigation(control.primaryContentPresenter);
                KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(control.primaryContentPresenter, KeyboardNavigationMode.None);

                control.overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                control.overlay.MoveFocus(traversalDirection);

                control.RaiseModalContentShownEvents();
            }
            else
            {
                control.overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(control.primaryContentPresenter, control.cachedKeyboardNavigationMode);
                control.primaryContentPresenter.MoveFocus(traversalDirection);

                control.RaiseModalContentHiddenEvents();
            }
        }

        private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ModalContentPresenter control = (ModalContentPresenter)d;

            if (e.OldValue != null)
                control.RemoveLogicalChild(e.OldValue);

            control.primaryContentPresenter.Content = e.NewValue;
            control.AddLogicalChild(e.NewValue);
            control.logicalChildren[0] = e.NewValue;
        }

        private static void OnModalContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ModalContentPresenter control = (ModalContentPresenter)d;

            if (e.OldValue != null)
                control.RemoveLogicalChild(e.OldValue);

            control.modalContentPresenter.Content = e.NewValue;
            control.AddLogicalChild(e.NewValue);
            control.logicalChildren[1] = e.NewValue;
        }

        private static void OnOverlayBrushChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ModalContentPresenter control = (ModalContentPresenter)d;
            control.overlay.Background = (Brush)e.NewValue;
        }
        #endregion

        #region FrameworkElement overrides
        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index > 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

            return layoutRoot;
        }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }

        protected override IEnumerator LogicalChildren
        {
            get { return logicalChildren.GetEnumerator(); }
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            layoutRoot.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));
            return finalSize;
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            layoutRoot.Measure(availableSize);
            return layoutRoot.DesiredSize;
        }
        #endregion

        #region layout panel
        class ModalContentPresenterPanel : Panel
        {
            protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
            {
                Size resultSize = new Size(0, 0);

                foreach (UIElement child in Children)
                {
                    child.Measure(availableSize);
                    resultSize.Width = Math.Max(resultSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Width);
                    resultSize.Height = Math.Max(resultSize.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
                }

                return resultSize;
            }

            protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
            {
                foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
                {
                    child.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));
                }

                return finalSize;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not MVVM, so do whatever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do this (at least, this is definitely not a MVVM-way).
Use `IsModal` property and data binding instead:

```
<Controls:ModalContentPresenter x:Name="modalContent" IsModal="{Binding IsModal}">
```

where `IsModal` in the binding expression is a bound data property within your view model.

Comment: I am the creator of the referenced `ModalContentPresenter` (see [here](https://github.com/BenjaminGale/ModalContentPresenter) and [here](http://programmingwithpassion.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/displaying-modal-content-in-wpf/)) and can confirm that this is the way the control was designed to be used in an MVVM compliant manner.

Answer (score 4):

In MVVM, any data going back and forth should be done via data binding properties on your View Model.  That includes virtually any properties of the `ContentPresenter` - just add a binding.  However, if you want call a method of a XAML object in an MVVM-friendly way, you can use an `Action`.

Let's suppose I wanted to set the focus on a textbox via the view model (contrived example, I know there's other MVVM-ways to do this- just wanted an example that requires a child object of the view).

First, give the textbox that should get the focus a name in your XAML, i.e.,

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1"/>
```

On your view model, add a property for the Action:

```
public Action FocusAction {get;set;}
```

Some time before or as your view is loading, get your DataContext (i.e., your view model) and add the Action to the code behind (the view's .cs file):

```
ViewModel vm = (ViewModel)this.DataContext;

if ( vm.FocusAction == null )
    vm.FocusAction= new Action(() => this.textBox1.Focus());
```

For instance, you might implement the IsLoaded event and do it there.  You could also do this in your constructor after InitializeComponent, as long as it either created your view model instance or it was passed in as a paramater.  The key is that the view model is already instantiated and assigned to the view's data context.

Then in your view model, wherever you wanted to add focus to that textbox, call:

```
FocusAction();
```

Since what I just showed above requires that your view cast the DataContext to a particular view model, what I do is create an interface for the kinds of actions I need, like this:

```
interface IFocusable
{
     Action FocusAction {get;set;}
}
```

Then I make my view model implement that inteface.  With that done, in my view's code-behind, I can say something like:

```
if(this.DataContext is IFocusable)
    ((IFocusable)this.DataContext).FocusAction = new Action(() => this.textBox1.Focus());
```

I think that makes it more MVVM-compliant, since it's not tightly-coupled to a particular view model, the view just knows it can add an action if the view model is the type of view model that can use it.

More details and another example available here: http://jkshay.com/closing-a-wpf-window-using-mvvm-and-minimal-
code-behind/

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been few years but I just faced the same, so here's my answer in case someone will find it useful...
In your xaml file refer to your ViewModel class in the DataContext:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:YourViewModel x:Name="yourViewModel"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

In your ViewModel class create a public function with your xaml file as argument and a private member to hold it:

```
private MainWindow mainWindow;

public void OnViewInitialized(MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
}
```

In your code behind use the function pass the the 'yourViewModel' you defined in the xaml:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    yourViewModel.OnViewInitialized(this);
}
```

And that's it :)
Now you can access all your xaml elements from your ViewModel by using your mainWindow member, just give them a name.

```
mainWindow.textBox1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a constructor for view model which accepts the ContentPage as its parameter.

```
public class ViewModelClass 
{
public ViewModelClass(ContentPage p=null)
{...}
}
```

then set the binding context in Contentpage back code script passing the referenc of contentpage to viewmodel

```
public class ContentPageClass : ContentPage
{
public ContentPageClass()
{
BindingContext = new ViewModelClass(p:this); 
}
}
```